# A Suggestion From an Outsider - Vote Early, Vote Often

Tags: discussion, voting

While this sort of thing has been said on many sites, I thought it might be worth saying here.

Vote early, vote often.

If a question is worthy of an answer, it's worthy of an upvote. If you don't feel like it deserves an upvote, you should probably (in my opinion, at least) be doing one of the following:

- edit, upvote, and answer
- flag for closure/vote for closure and don't answer
- ask for clarification or something else from OP and don't answer

If an answer helped you, it's worthy of an upvote. If an answer answers a question (no matter if you answered it as well) it is worthy of an upvote. If it makes you uncomfortable to upvote the answer, edit to improve it, flag it as low quality, ask for clarification from the author, and above all, answer the question as well yourself (if it is on-topic, in which case see the above point about questions).

Let's use the votes we're given.

Also, in a not-as-reasoned point: if it's good, why *not* upvote it? I don't know about you, but I get warm fuzzies every time I see that green "+10" or "+5" because I know my contributions helped someone. And, while we all know that those fantastic meaningless internet points aren't, well, the point, why not brighten someone's day if they did a good job?

As I said in this post's title, I am an outsider to the site, but I have experienced sites which do this, and sites which don't. Be the site that does.

Here's to hoping that a graduation party is coming soon! =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Writers Graduate? Correlation between voting and progressing?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/can-writers-graduate-correlation-between-voting-and-progressing)